# Get all records of 'key field' where any of the records that contains it matches a word

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the next records in my index

```
[
  {
    "filekey": "book1",
    "word": "salomon",
    "page": 1
  },
  {
    "filekey": "book1",
    "word": "testament",
    "page": 2
  },
  {
    "filekey": "book2",
    "word": "salomon",
    "page": 1
  },
  {
    "filekey": "book2",
    "word": "testament",
    "page": 2
  },
  {
    "filekey": "book3",
    "word": "salomon",
    "page": 1,
  },
  {
    "filekey": "book3",
    "word": "license",
    "page": 2
  },
]
```

What i want to do is get records based on two filters, the filters are based on two texts:

1. 'testament'
2. 'salomon'

In First filter i should get the records of any **filekeys** where **word** matches 'testament', so:

```
[
  {
    "filekey": "book1",
    "word": "salomon",
    "page": 1
  },
  {
    "filekey": "book1",
    "word": "testament",
    "page": 2
  },
  {
    "filekey": "book2",
    "word": "salomon",
    "page": 1
  },
  {
    "filekey": "book2",
    "word": "testament",
    "page": 2
  }
]
```

**book3** is discarded because none of it's records **word** matches 'testment'

In Second filter i should get the records where **word** matches 'salomon', so:

```
[
  {
    "filekey": "book1",
    "word": "salomon",
    "page": 1
  },
  {
    "filekey": "book2",
    "word": "salomon",
    "page": 1
  }
]
```

In the production elastic base i'm working on has MILLIONS of these records
is it possible to achieve this in elastic?

Comment: Do you want to get only those records that match `testament` or `salomon` ?

Comment: it looks like my example isn't very clear, but think of the elements of the index as  pages in a book. So each element must have the word, the page and the name of the book. In the first filter i want to get all pages of all books in the condition that ANY of it's pages contain the word 'testament', and the second filter is to find in those pages the specific page that contains the word 'salomon'. I updated the example hoping is more clear :D